# How can I mass delete multilingual strings when I know only the page that added them?

Tags: i18n-l10n

Some inappropriately placed `t()` functions generated a large number of strings that I do not want to translate.  Unfortunately, using the `Refresh strings` i18n page does not clear these strings.

On the `Translate interface` page, I can search for the strings one by one and delete them but there are about a hundred so I would prefer to do it another way.  Thankfully, they were all created on two pages, so I can search by the path (`/ja/mypage`) and delete them that way.  However, I still have to click each link.

Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
drush sql-query "delete from locales_source where location = '/ja/mypage'"
```

Or delete by strings, for examples if all strings you want to delete contains "hoof" :

```
drush sql-query "delete from locales_source where source like '%hoof%'"
```